# How do I add ROW_NUMBER to a LINQ query or Entity?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm stumped by this easy data problem.

I'm using the Entity framework and have a database of products.  My results page returns a paginated list of these products.  Right now my results are ordered by the number of sales of each product, so my code looks like this:

```
return Products.OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count());
```

This returns an IQueryable dataset of my entities, sorted by the number of sales.

I want my results page to show the rank of each product (in the dataset).  My results should look like this:

```
Page #1
1. Bananas
2. Apples
3. Coffee

Page #2
4. Cookies
5. Ice Cream
6. Lettuce
```

I'm expecting that I just want to add a column in my results using the SQL ROW_NUMBER variable...but I don't know how to add this column to my results datatable.

My resulting page does contain a foreach loop, but since I'm using a paginated set I'm guessing using that number to fake a ranking number would NOT be the best approach.

So my question is, how do I add a ROW_NUMBER column to my query results in this case?

Comment: It sounds like this could be a presentation layer concern that could be addressed by calculating it. `var rank = (pageIndex * pageSize) + rowIndex + 1;`

Comment: Before anyone else attempts to do this with Model-Defined functions, Neither Entity SQL nor the SqlServer namespace support `ROW_NUMBER()`. Looks like in-memory is the only way to do it with Entity Framework, as offered by the answers on this post.

Answer (score 33):

Nothing directly translates to `ROW_NUMBER` in LINQ to Entities. As an in-memory workaround, you can use the [indexed overload of Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-1)))):

```
var start = page * rowsPerPage;
Products.OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count())
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(rowsPerPage)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((u, index) => new { Product = u, Index = index + start });
```

Comment: Don't know if this matters, but this is going to be difficult to pass around, because it is an anonymous object.

Comment: You don't have to use an anonymous type. Create a non-anonymous type and use that if you need to. It's just an example.

Comment: When I try this out I get NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 [...] method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Which suggests to me that this index overload isn't supported by the EF provider.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: That's right, you need to add an `.AsEnumerable()`. I should add that.

Comment: @JohnGietzen, I'm well aware of that, but if you read his question, `ROW_NUMBER` isn't actually what he needs. He says, 'My results should look like this:", and that's what this code does.

Comment: Too bad the Linq to Entities provider doesn't use sql "ROW_NUMBER()" internall to prevent you from having to use .AsEnuerable() along with this indexed overload of the Select statement, which seems like in some cases might result in unnecessarily large result sets being retrieved from the data store.

Comment: Suggesting to use AsEnumerable() when clearly asking for an sql function (ROW_NUMBER) is a complete non-answer.

Comment: This starts at 0 for each "page".

Answer (score 4):

Actually using OrderBy and then Skip + Take generates ROW_NUMBER in EF 4.5 (you can check with SQL Profiler).

I was searching for a way to do the same thing you are asking for and I was able to get what I need through a simplification of Craig's answer:

```
var start = page * rowsPerPage;
Products.OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count())
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(rowsPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

By the way, the generated SQL uses ROW_NUMBER > start and TOP rowsPerPage.

Comment: Well, the query itself generates a `ROW_NUMBER()`, but only as an intermediate step for `ORDER BY`. This doesn't let me select it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = Products.OrderByDecending(u => u.Sales.Count());
var y = x.ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < y.Count; i++) {
    int myNumber = i; // this is your order number
}
```

As long as the list stays in the same order, which should happen unless the sales number changes.  You could be able to get an accurate count;

There is also this way of doing it.

```
var page = 2;
var count = 10;
var startIndex = page * count;

var x = Products.OrderByDecending(u => u.Sales.Count());
var y = x.Skip(startIndex).Take(count);
```

This gives the start index for the page, plus it gives you a small set of sales to display on the page.  You just start the counting on your website at startIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long winded answer. First create a class to house the number/item pair like so:

```
public class NumberedItem<T>
{
    public readonly int Number;
    public readonly T Item;

    public NumberedItem(int number, T item)
    {
        Item = item;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

Next comes an abstraction around a page of items (numbered or not):

```
class PageOf<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly int startsAt;
    private IEnumerable<T> items;

    public PageOf(int startsAt, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.startsAt = startsAt;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerable<NumberedItem<T>> NumberedItems
    {
        get
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
                yield return new NumberedItem<T>(startsAt + index++, item);
            yield break;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            yield return item;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Once you have that you can "Paginate" a particular queryable collection using this:

```
class PaginatedQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly int PageSize;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> Source;

    public PaginatedQueryable(int PageSize, IQueryable<T> Source)
    {
        this.PageSize = PageSize;
        this.Source = Source;
    }

    public PageOf<T> Page(int pageNum)
    {
        var start = (pageNum - 1) * PageSize;
        return new PageOf<T>(start + 1, Source.Skip(start).Take(PageSize));
    }
}
```

And finally a nice extension method to cover the ugly:

```
static class PaginationExtension
{
    public static PaginatedQueryable<T> InPagesOf<T>(this IQueryable<T> target, int PageSize)
    {
        return new PaginatedQueryable<T>(PageSize, target);
    }
}
```

Which means you can now do this:

```
var products = Products.OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count()).InPagesOf(20).Page(1);

foreach (var product in products.NumberedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", product.Number, product.Item);
}
```