# How to find the ROW_NUMBER() of a row with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Linq to SQL makes use of `ROW_NUMBER()` for paging purposes, i.e. When you use Skip() and Take().

However, I can't seem to find a way of actually accessing `ROW_NUMBER()` values myself in the query. I need to find the ROW_NUMBER() of a record within a query (**without bringing all the records back**).

I've done this successfuly in T-SQL and Linq to Objects, but a Linq to SQL solution is proving elusive.

In Linq to Objects I can get the row number like this:

```
var rowTarget =
    mainQuery
        .Select((obj, index) => new { obj.ID, Index = index })
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == targetID);

// rowTarget.Index is the answer
```

But Linq to SQL does not support the overrides of `Select()` that use an index parameter (and that makes sense, really - `ROW_NUMBER()` would only be used if Skip() and Take() were being used).

I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't result in all records being returned from the database.

Is this even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-rownumber-to-a-linq-query-or-entity

duplicate?

Comment: @bassfriend - EF and LINQ-to-SQL have completely different support for such operations...

Comment: I was kind of hoping to see an answer here. I'm running into the same issue - the indexed overload doesn't work w/L2S. I'd be happy w/any incremental ID; guess I'll have to do it in multiple steps.

Answer (score 2):

(edit: tried it; still gives "`Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'`")...

Why are you using `SelectMany` here? Have you tried it with the version of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx) that includes the index?

```
.Select((obj, index) => new { obj.ID, Index = index })
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == targetID);
```

You should also probably include an explicit `OrderBy` - LINQ-to-SQL lets you get away without it most of the time, but EF doesn't.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the query. But yeah, as you say, still not supported. :(

Answer (score -2):

You have to include AsEnumerable()

i.e .

```
var rowTarget = 
    mainQuery.AsEnumerable() 
        .Select((obj, index) => new { obj.ID, Index = index }) 
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == targetID);
```

Comment: `AsEnumerable` will pull down all records from the database, so it defeats the purpose.

Comment: Downvoting this as it currently appears at the top but like DotNetWise says, it isn't a solution.