# Linq2Sql: Get every N'th row

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to SQL Every Nth Row From Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208366/linq-to-sql-every-nth-row-from-table)

This doens't work in Linq2Sql:

```
context.Enquirys.Where((e, index) => (index % g) == gs);
```

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: it's even quite hard to do this using sql so I guess no ORM framework will support this natively as query operator

Comment: Closing as duplicate, but I have a [fresh answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208366/linq-to-sql-every-nth-row-from-table/4216935#4216935)  I intend adding to the [linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208366/linq-to-sql-every-nth-row-from-table)