# Select every nth row with NHibernate

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

How would you implement a query that selects every nth row, with NHibernate QueryOver, HQL or Criteria?

Currently I use the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [Row]
    FROM [TABLE_NAME]
) x WHERE (x.[Row] % 100) = 0
```

(Thanks to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208366/linq-to-sql-every-nth-row-from-table))

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the solution of using an indexing table in a cross join? What I mean is that you have a table with as many rows as you think you will need with an indexed column of integers going from 1-n in each row. This can be in a master database perhaps with a date column beside it - its amazing how useful this method is. The query would then look like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [Row]
    FROM [TABLE_NAME]
) x INNER JOIN [Index_Table] i ON i.Id*100=x.[Row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as L2S - there's no *easy* way to do this without SQL. And the syntax would be DBMS-specific anyway.

Comment: The solution using row_number() is pretty DBMS independent (as all modern DBMS support that nowadays). The only thing that is DBMS dependent is the modulo operator.