# VB.NET - LINQ to SQL - How do I add in Row_Number to a LINQ to SQL query in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

[How do I add ROW_NUMBER to a LINQ query or Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity)

How can I convert this solution to VB.NET?

```
var start = page * rowsPerPage;
Products.OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count())
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(rowsPerPage)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((u, index) => new { Product = u, Index = index + start }); // this line gets me
```

I'm having trouble porting that last line. I have been unable to locate a VB.NET example.

I'm actually not looking for any paging functionality like the example provides, just good old-fashioned `Row_Number(Order By X)` row index.

Comment: What is the purpose of the OrderByDescending(u => u.Sales.Count()) in this example? Since the count doesn't change during the query, this effectively does nothing other than spin cycles (assuming SQL doesn't optimize it out of the execution plan).

Comment: I don't know. This is a code snippet from another Stackoverflow post. I'm interested in projecting a row index into the list of anon objects in VB.NET

Comment: In that case, use the overload in Select David B mentioned below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LinqToSql can't do a Row_Number(Order By X) in the database.

The c# code you posted does it against in-memory instances by calling Enumerable.Select

On the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) for Enumerable.Select, there's a vb.net example.

---

**Here is a working example that demonstrates the projection of a row index in VB.NET:**

```
Dim R = (
     From P In DB.Products Select P
  ).AsEnumerable().Select(
     Function(Product, index) New With {index, Product}
  )

Response.Write(R(12).Product.Doc_width.ToString()) 'Access object members
Response.Write(R(12).index.ToString() 'Access Row Index
```