# Add ROW_NUMBER to a LINQ query for specific Entity?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, row-number

I need an EF query to get the row number of a specific entity.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259737/get-row-index-in-a-list-by-using-entity-framework).

Currently I have it working in this way:

```
    private DbContext Context;
    public int GetRowNumberQuery<TEntity>(int entityId)
    {
        var allEntities = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();

        return allEntities
            .Select((entity, index) => new { Index = index, Entity = entity })
            .Where(x => x.Entity.Id == entityId)
            .Select(x => x.Index)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Obviously, this is very inefficient as it gets a list of all entities before selecting the index. If I remove the .ToList() in the first line, making the whole thing a LINQ query, it fails at the first Select with NotSupportedException saying:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,MyEntityType]]
>   Select[MyEntityType,<>f__AnonymousType1`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyEntityType],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[MyEntityType,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,MyEntityType]]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can you please tell me how to get the ROW_NUMBER of a specific entity?
Or is it impossible like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258097/vb-net-linq-to-sql-how-do-i-add-in-row-number-to-a-linq-to-sql-query-in-vb-n) pretty old question suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Entity Framework doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()` (the examples given use EF to generate a query and then "attach" a number to each returned row client side, starting from 1 and going to n if there are n rows)

B) Even in TSQL the query would be complex:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RN FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = 100
```

would return `NULL` if there are no rows or `1` if there is a row with ID 100

You would need something like

```
SELECT B.RN 
    FROM 
        (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RN 
            FROM SomeTable) B 
    WHERE B.ID = 100
```

C) Clearly you can create a view/stored procedure that uses `ROW_NUMBER`and call it from EF