# row number with help of linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

my table consists of 3 columns(sno,name,age) now i am retrieving this table from the database with extra column(row number) ,i used the following code

```
select * from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SNo asc)as rowindex,SNo,Name,Age 
    from tblExample) 
    as example where rowindex between ((pageindex*10)+1) and ((pageindex+1)*10)
```

note:here pageindex is the varaible that takes some intger value which is passed by the user

my data base is sql server 2008, now i want to write the same query using **linq**

can any one please change the abovesql query into linq. iam unable to do it as iam new to linq. iam struck up with this problem please help me thank you in advance

Comment: something like context.tlbExample.OrderBy(x => x.SNo).Skip(pageindex*10).Take(10).Select((i,x) => new { rowindex = i + pageindex*10 + 1, x.SNo, x.Name, x.Age})

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add ROW\_NUMBER to a LINQ query or Entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write query as beow

```
var index=1;
            var pageIndex=1;
            var pageSize = 10;
            data.Select(x => new
            {
                RowIndex = index++,
                Sno = x.Sno,
                Name = x.Name,
                Age = x.Age
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Skip(pageSize * (pageIndex - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for your concern. i copied your code. iam getting error near data.Select "data does not exists in the current context

Comment: `data` is your object of `tblExample` from EntityDataModel and also make sure you have imported `System.Linq` namespace