# Entity Framework SqlQuery not returning row_number() value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a SELECT statement that returns row_number() value with all other fields from table. Query is pretty simple and is working in SSMS:

```
SELECT 
    *, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TablePrimaryKey) AS INT) AS [RowNumber]
FROM 
    TableName 
WHERE 
    TablePrimaryKey > 10
```

(In real application `WHERE` statement is much more complex, but for simplicity I put it like this)

In my project I created a POCO class that contains `RowNumber` property (with all other necessary properties)

```
...
public int RowNumber { get; set; }
...
```

And I made sure migrations won't create additional columns in table at my `entityConfiguration` class:

```
this.Ignore(x => x.RowNumber);
```

Problem is that with Entity Framework's `SqlQuery()` method it returns all columns from the table as it should, but `RowNumber` is always 0. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 version. Did I miss something, or can this not be done this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add ROW\_NUMBER to a LINQ query or Entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity)

Comment: I saw that answer, and it works but i came to other problem. To get a list of objects from databse with row_number value in that way works well. 

Problem is what if user wants to get specifically record with row_number() value of 2 in the way we dont have to always return all records from database and then search for that record in return list?

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework - *why* are you using `SqlQuery` and not the "native" Linq querying that EF offers?

Comment: Ok, can you help me how to write this query with Linq:

WITH main AS (
SELECT *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrimaryKeyId) AS 'RowNumber'
  FROM [TableName]
  WHERE [month] = 10 AND [year] = 2014
)
SELECT * FROM main WHERE RowNumber = 2

All I want is that on my edit page of ASP.MVC project i get row_number() value for that record with all other properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer your question in comment.

> WITH main AS ( SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrimaryKeyId) AS
>   'RowNumber' FROM [TableName] WHERE [month] = 10 AND [year] = 2014 )
>   SELECT * FROM main WHERE RowNumber = 2

C#/EF code:

```
int RowNumber = 2;
var row = TableName.OrderBy(t=>t.PrimaryKeyId).Skip(RowNumber -1).Take(1);
```

The SQL generated looks like:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1

SELECT [t1].[ID], [t1].c1 FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[ID]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
           [t0].[ID], [t0].c1
    FROM [TableName] AS [t0]
) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

I am using Linq-to-SQL, EF should be similar: the sorting is on server side, and it returns 1 record only.